# dollar($) -variable assignment is not working in my sed command

Tags: unix, sed, solaris

The below command works fine.

sed -n '/9/1/16 2:22/,/9/1/16 2:23/ p' /app/err.txt

But when i do it in below way the command results nothing:

```
$ s1="9\/1\/16"
$ t1="2:22"
$ s2="9\/1\/16"
$ t2="2:23"
$ sed -n '/$s1 $t1/,/$s2 $t2/ p' /app/err.txt
```

Please let me know how can i achieve it..!?

Comment: `sed -n "/$s1 $t1/,/$s2 $t2/ p" /app/err.txt` . Better to use `@` for `s@...@...@`. Good luck.

Comment: strange that `sed -n '/9/1/16 2:22/,/9/1/16 2:23/ p' /app/err.txt` worked fine

Comment: @shellter it worked..! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use double quotes instead of single quotes with variables, e.g. "$s1". And `|` separators instead of `/`.

Comment: sed -n "/$s1 $t1/,/$s2 $t2/ p" /app/err.txt